# Broadleaf Admin Panel Extend Spring Boot in ReactStarter

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I want to extend Admin Panel to see order received. i tried folowing [Tutorial](https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/broadleaf-concepts/admin/admin-custom-controllers) ,But could not find applicationContext-servlet-admin.xml. Is the tutorials still relevent with spring boot ?  Can you please help ?

Answer (score 2):

That tutorial is slightly out of date. Step 2 in that tutorial looks to be the only issue. Instead of updating an XML file, you would now load servlet beans in AdminServletConfig.java